# How to determine last LSN that affected a given table?

Tags: postgresql

My goal is to compute some kind of version over the entire table.

Assuming that logical replication is already set up, I can use `pg_publication_tables` to see what publications a given table is included in.

I'm having trouble figuring out of Postgres keeps track of last LSN per publication.

Maybe there's some other statistic I could use? Or some hack I could use to map LSN back to a table?

Answer (score 1):

In general, in order to check information about subscriptions you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_subscription
```

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-subscription.html

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_subscription
```

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-SUBSCRIPTION

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots
```

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-replication-slots.html

To identify the last LSN you can use **recieved_lsn** from **pg_stat_subscription** on destination, or  **confirmed_flush_lsn** from **pg_replication_slots** on source. I would say that based on the documendation, the way to go is **confirmed_flush_lsn**

Comment: How does that LSN collate with the specific table(s) that were affected by that transaction?

Comment: LSN is not per table, is just a long number representing the position in the WAL, check this post, which shows a way to get information of the log https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281584/how-to-get-lsnxid-numbers-of-transactions-from-wal-file. One other way is to use PGLogical extension, I think there you can have the Last LSN per table within a publication.